# Phirehose setTrack not working with setLocation

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, phirehose

I'm using Phirehose to pull tweets using the Twitter Streaming API. I'm wanting to pull geotagged tweets with certain keywords, like so:

```
$sc->setLocations(array(array(-180,-90,180,90))); //any geotagged tweet
$sc->setTrack($sc->getKeywords());
```

getKeywords class function looks like:

```
public function getKeywords()
{
     $array = array('hurricane', 'flood', 'tornado','tsunami','earthquake');
     return $array; 
}
```

The problem is that `setLocation()` seems to cause `setTrack()` to not pull tweets with those keywords. If I remove `setLocation()` altogether, `setTrack()` pulls keywords fine. Is there any way I can pull geotagged tweets containing those keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The track, follow, and locations fields should be considered to be combined with an OR operator. track=foo&follow=1234 returns Tweets matching “foo” OR created by user 1234."

As said from Twitter's guys in https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter